# Highly steeped-hill with heavy car with manual transmission

Tags: engine, stall, rpm

So, there's this really steeped hill to access my grandfather's house. Accessing it downhill is not difficult by using first gear. However, climbing it is the difficult thing. What to do when you are climbing it, first gear, and mid-climb the RPMs are too low the engine's about to stall? What to do to avoid the stalling, avoid the braking entirely because to start is difficult and rolling backwards is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your vehicle doesn't have a low-range gearbox so personally my suggestion would be to open the throttle.  This does however seem to be more about driving technique which isn't strictly what MVM&R focuses on.